# Unique name with index

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to create a view that will produce unique entity name with index for each unique sequence of `entity_id, entity_type, entity_name` columns.

| entity_id | entity_type | entity_name | entity_name_id (serial) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | t | cosmic-alex | 1 |
| 1 | t | cosmic-alex | 2 |
| 2 | t | cosmic-alex | 3 |

Expected result:

| entity_id | entity_type | entity_name | unique_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | t | cosmic-alex | cosmic-alex-1 |
| 1 | t | cosmic-alex | cosmic-alex-1 |
| 2 | t | cosmic-alex | cosmic-alex-2 |

```
CREATE VIEW ranked_entities AS
  SELECT
    rs.entity_type,
    rs.entity_id,
    rs.entity_name || '-' || rs.unique_name_rank AS unique_name
  FROM (
    SELECT
      entity_type,
      entity_id,
      entity_name,
      rank() OVER (PARTITION BY entity_name ORDER BY entity_name_id) unique_name_rank
    FROM table_1
  ) rs
;
```

Comment: I'm not sure how the query you've included relates to your question. It seems like you want to include the entity_id in the unique name, but then you're using a generated rank field instead?

Comment: Simply add rs.entity_name before your unique_name derived field.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
create view ranked_entities as
select
  r.entity_type,
  r.entity_id,
  r.entity_name,
  r.entity_name || '-' || g.rn as unique_name
from table_1 r
join (
  select entity_type, entity_id, entity_name, row_number() 
    over(order by entity_type, entity_id, entity_name) as rn
  from table_1
  group by entity_type, entity_id, entity_name
) g on (g.entity_type, g.entity_id, g.entity_name) 
     = (r.entity_type, r.entity_id, r.entity_name);
```

Result:

```
 entity_type  entity_id  entity_name  unique_name   
 ------------ ---------- ------------ ------------- 
 t            1          cosmix-alex  cosmix-alex-1 
 t            1          cosmix-alex  cosmix-alex-1 
 t            2          cosmix-alex  cosmix-alex-2
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vPFyMb1KVydFh6SQUHHbg1/0).

Comment: I've tried it before, but but this has the opposite effect: cosmic-alex-1, cosmic-alex-2, cosmic-alex-1 (each unique sequence starts from the beginning)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data, the simplest method is:

```
rs.entity_name || '-' || entity_id AS unique_name
```

However, I think that is an artifact of your sample data.  Instead, go for `dense_rank()` but without `partition by`:

```
rs.entity_name || '-' || dense_rank() over (order by entity-id, entity_type, entity_name) AS unique_name
```

I'm not sure if `entity_type` and `entity_name` are needed.  It might be sufficient to just use `entity_id`.